# What is the context switching time?

Tags: operating-system, multithreading, scheduling

I have a doubt in context switching.
In multi threading, when the context switching occurs, what will be the time between two context switches? Is it fixed time interval?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is really OS and situation dependent. You'll have to read about [scheduling in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_algorithm) and about the specific threading technology you use: [there is a nice list here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Scheduling).

When considering threads, the real wall-time intervals might change if other processes need CPU time, by that taking time from the process running the threads.

That being said, [there are some nice C code samples to measure that time](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.development.system/2007-04/msg00043.html).